# How to mark a directory as library root?

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, webstorm

I've 2 projects in PhpStorm: one is working well while another won't work and I can't figure what make the first one working.

The first one is working well with library root for bower, npm and composer :

[image]

The second one is bower, npm are not detected as library root : 
[image]

So the behaviour in PhpStorm is different, when I use the navigate file on second project, I see all the vendor file by default :

[image]

If I mark the directory as excluded, the ide don't understand the vendor class : 
[image]

So how can we configure the IDE to mark a directory as library root ?

Comment: So .. is this a JavaScript code that we talking about here? Because it depends on actual language. **For PHP** -- `Settings/Preferences | Languages & Frameworks | PHP | Include Paths` -- a folder added here will be treated as a External Library. You can now mark such folder as Excluded -- this way the errors/todo and other stuff from here will not be treated as part of the project code but code completion will still be available (as it's a Library code now).

Comment: Similar kind of story should be done for JavaScript -- look under `Languages & Frameworks | JavaScript | Libraries`. I'm not JavaScript person (just basic jQuery usage) .. so not 100% sure on this .. but I believe it it should be handled by IDE automatically based on your `package.json` and alike.

Comment: Few links: 1) https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2014/07/how-webstorm-works-completion-for-javascript-libraries/ 2) https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2010/11/working-with-javascript-libraries-in-phpstorm-webstorm/

Comment: thx @LazyOne, for the php file, the include path works well, it's true. But for javascript files, it's not so simple. Another precision, I use npm for webpack (so exclude path is nice) and bower for public assets and it's this one that don't work as expected

Comment: As I see you have updated your Question with some solution. Please post it as an actual Answer and accept it -- it might be useful for others in similar situation. Right now your ticket looks like unanswered when searched...

Comment: any idea how to also make Storm be able to go navigate to the library root when CMD+Clicking? (go to definiton)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Thanks to @LazyOne comment, found the solution : Select Preferences | Languages & Frameworks | JavaScript | Libraries and click Add. Select the path you want to add and the folder will be marked as library root. Really useful for non standard path (not bower_components for example)

Comment: Also to note, for me "Add Directory" was grayed out if I selected the framework at the top of the dialog first. When I tried again without selecting anything and trying to add my directory first, then IntelliJ auto-populated the fields at the top.

Answer (score 10):

**Found** a solution that worked for me.

I opened the `.idea` folder (in sublime), searched all files for the text `node_modules` and removed the lines containing it.

In my case I had 2 entries

- `workspace.xml`

`<property name="ts.external.directory.path" value="$PROJECT_DIR$/node_modules/typescript/lib" />`

- `project-name.iml`

`<content url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/node_modules" />`

Now my `node_modules` directory is automatically marked as `library root` again

Answer (score 6):

- `File` > `Settings` > `Directories`
- Remove any `node_modules` entries (right-hand side, x's)

Thank you to @Allisone for providing the manual solution.

Based on their response, I was able to replicate the solution using the settings.

Comment: This was the answer for me, thank you so much! At some point I had marked it as some other kind of root, and this was apparently the only place I could remove that designation.

Answer (score 1):

#### Option 1

Go to `File` > `Project Structure`

[image]

Go to `Project Settings` > `Modules` and remove the library folder (i.e. `/node_modules`) from **both** the *Excluded folders* and *Content root* sections.

[image: Content root library folder and excluded folder node_nodules]

Your project structure will look like this:

[image]

Last, restart IntelliJ.

#### Option 2

Go to your project IntelliJ file `<your-project>.iml` found on the root folder and remove the lines containing the library path (using `/node_modules` as example):

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module type="WEB_MODULE" version="4">
  <component name="NewModuleRootManager" inherit-compiler-output="true">
    <exclude-output />
    <content url="file://$MODULE_DIR$">
      <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/dist" />
      <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/node_modules" />
    </content>
    <content url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/node_modules" />
    <orderEntry type="inheritedJdk" />
    <orderEntry type="sourceFolder" forTests="false" />
  </component>
</module>
```

Your project structure should go back to normal.

[image]