# WebStorm - make node_modules "library root" but also exclude it from indexing

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webstorm, node-modules

Is there a way to configure a WebStorm project that so `node_modules` is selected as `library root` but that it's also excluded from indexing?

I swear I saw a project that indicated `node_modules` was both `library root` and `excluded` but I can't figure out how to set that up. Anybody know how?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it's impossible. Because `library root` means "index a part of node_modules corresponding to direct dependencies from package.json, and exclude the rest part of it (i.e. indirect dependencies - dependencies of dependencies)" and `excluded` means "exclude the whole node_modules (i.e. both direct and indirect dependencies)".

If you want to have node_modules `excluded`, just go to "Settings | Languages & Frameworks | JavaScript | Libraries" and unselect corresponding node_modules library.

Comment: I am not sure if it's mpossible, for some projects I still see node_module as excluded and library root.

Answer (score -1):

At this time, it is possible to exclude a `library root` folder.

[image]

Configuring a `library root` folder is explained [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44951671/4452244). Here is the relevant part:

> Select Preferences | Languages & Frameworks | JavaScript | Libraries and click Add. Select the path you want to add and the folder will be marked as library root.

Then, the `library root` folder can be excluded.

Excluded directories are hidden in the project's tree (unless you asked to show excluded folders, of course). Phpstorm still references classes and functions in the `library root` folder. Javascript's `require` and `import` still work and navigating to a file is possible.